# Deleted tasks still showing in celery

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery, supervisord

I've completely removeed all records of of celery tasks in `settings.py`, `celery.py` and `tasks.py` except for one which is called `test_post`.

However an error relating to an old task is still showing in my `celery.log` file:

```
[2018-05-08 07:23:05,115: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type 'post_jobs'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you're using relative imports?

Please see
http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/internals/protocol.html
for more information.

The full contents of the message body was:
'[[], {}, {"chord": null, "chain": null, "errbacks": null, "callbacks": null}]' (77b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/james/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 561, in on_task_received
    strategy = strategies[type_]
KeyError: 'post_jobs'
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

I've already tried `celery -A myapp purge` and it didn't do anything.

Comment: did you restart your `beat` ?

Comment: run command:  `celery -A prj worker --beat --scheduler django --loglevel=info`

Comment: Just tried that and it's still sending deleted jobs, e.g. `[2018-05-08 07:35:00,321: INFO/Beat] Scheduler: Sending due task post_jobs (post_jobs)`

Comment: delete it from database

Comment: ah yes I think that may have solved it. the old tasks were still in `django-celery-beat>periodic tasks` in my django admin. thankyou!